# SQL- Referencing the primary key of the current relation (homework)

Tags: sql

I'm working on a DB  system for a university holding teachers, courses, students, and so on. In my student relation I'd like to include an attribute name Mentor the value of which would be student(SID). What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Sounds like a foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly the Mentor would be another student so you'd have a self-referencing foreign key. That is, the foreign key on Mentor would reference the same table that contains the Mentor (i.e. Student).

You don't say which RDBMS you're using so the following is pseudocode rather than the actual SQL for any particular database.

```
create table Student
    StudentId int primary key
    MendtorId int foreign key references Student.StudentId
```